How to calculate eigenvalues of Hodge-Laplacian $\Delta_d$ acting on one-forms on the round sphere $(\mathbb{S}^2,g)$?
On the round two sphere $(\mathbb{S}^2,g)$, we have the Hodge Laplacian operator $\Delta_d=dd^{*}+d^{*}d$ acting on one-forms. I want to calculate its eigenvalues.
I know $\sigma(\Delta_d)\setminus{\{0\}}=\sigma(dd^{*})\setminus{\{ 0\}}\bigcup \sigma(d^{*}d)\setminus{\{ 0\}}$ from Theorem 3.3.1 in Jost's  "Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis". So I want to calculate the eigenvalues of $\Delta_d$ acting on closed one-forms and co-closed one-forms. But I have no idea how to calculate this.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!
